# IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.io.Files.fileTreeTraverser()

Tags: android

I'm getting the following error on all app builds since this morning:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':MyProject:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForQaDebug'.
> tried to access method com.google.common.io.Files.fileTreeTraverser()Lcom/google/common/collect/TreeTraverser; from class com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunVerifierTransform

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':MyProject:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForQaDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:273)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:258)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.io.Files.fileTreeTraverser()Lcom/google/common/collect/TreeTraverser; from class com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunVerifierTransform
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunVerifierTransform.processFolderInputs(InstantRunVerifierTransform.java:165)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunVerifierTransform.doTransform(InstantRunVerifierTransform.java:139)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunVerifierTransform.transform(InstantRunVerifierTransform.java:120)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor895.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    ... 34 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
```

Not aware of any updates, it's weird that this started happening all of a sudden.

Note that the problem seems to be in accessing the method `Files.fileTreeTraverser()` from class `com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunVerifierTransform` but even when I disable Instant Run, the build still fails to access `Files.fileTreeTraverser()` from class `com.android.utils.FileUtils`.

Any ideas on where it's coming from and how to fix it, please?

Comment: I am facing similar kind of issue. Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be in Artifactory's Build Info Extractor.

We were pointing to the latest release of the library so when they released a new version (on the 10th of Feb) we didn't notice. Downgrading to the one before the last version helped for some builds but not all, so we had to go two versions down:

Instead of

```
classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:latest.release"
```

Use

```
classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.9.0"
```

Comment: I experienced this same bug using version 4.9.7 and rolling back to 4.9.0 helped me run my app locally. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
```

and

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
```

and if you have

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem in my flutter project. I fixed by steps as below:

update file:
 **/android/build.gradle**

- change: ext.kotlin_version

> ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'

- change: com.android.tools.build:gradle

> ```
> dependencies {
>   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
>   ...
> ```

Hopefully, it's helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same error in my flutter app and the following steps solved my problem:

1. In the build script, change the kotline version to

   ```
   buildscript {
       ext.kotlin_version =  '1.3.31'
   }
   ```
2. Within the dependencies make sure the version of gradle is

   ```
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
   }
   ```
3. Also make sure the dependency version of google services is:

   ```
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error by changing

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

in my gradle